# difference between eband_local_planner and teb_local planner

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner, eband-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly is the difference between teb and eband local planner and how exactly do they work differently ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242067/difference-between-eband_local_planner-and-teb_local-planner/) by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[eband_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/eband_local_planner) (classical Elastic Band approach by Quinlan et al.) and [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) (Timed Elastic Band (TEB) approach) are two completely different planning algorithms. However, the TEB principle is based on the classic elastic band idea.

**eband_local_planner (Elastic Band)**

- Local path deformation (path: no timing law) based on internal and external forces
- Internal forces contract the path (-> leading to the shortest path between start and goal)
- External forces repel the path from obstacles
- Implementation based on bubbles that represent discrete path points and free-space.
- Adaption of the trajectory length w.r.t. bubbles/free-space (insertion and deletion of discrete points)
- Extension to non-holonomic kinematics (supports differential-drive and omnidirectional robots)
- Subject to local minima (e.g. left or right path around an obstacle, depends on initial path)

**teb_local_planner (Timed Elastic Band)**

- Local trajectory deformation/optimization (trajectory: includes temporal information)
- Instead of generating and applying forces, an objective/cost function is minimized
- Temporal information is subject to optimization -> time-optimal trajectories (replacement for the internal forces)
- Temporal information allows incorporation of (kino-)dynamic constraints during optimization (no need for a dedicated path-following controller, the teb_local_planner mimics a predictive controller)
- Adaptation of the trajectory length based on the temporal discretization (insertion and deletion of discrete trajectory points)
- Supports differential-drive, car-like and omnidirectional robots
- Explores multiple distinctive topologies for parallel trajectory optimization in order to partially overcome the local minima problem (only in the scope of the local costmap due to limited CPU resources, a global planner is still required).
- Path-following mode (minimize distance to global plan instead of minimizing transition time)
- Bottleneck: very high computational burden (-> limited local costmap size/resolution resp. robot size).

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on 2016-08-19**:
thanks and what do you think i should use if i want to avoid dynamic obstacles from laser scan

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2019-12-13**:
@rajnunes He's the developer of the `teb_local_planner` so he probably thought that it isn't very appropriate to point out directly. But instead, the answer shows that `teb_local_planner` is newer and has more benefits. I thought about saying it because I feel like, time to time, visitors upvoted your comment so I awaken a dead question.